# count news in category with a sql query

Tags: sql

I have a news and news_categories table. news_category_id column in news table.

Now I want to show a news category list in page. So I write a sql to query:

```
select count(n.id) as news_count, c.`id`, c.name from news n
    inner join news_categories c 
    on c.id = n.`news_category_id`
    group by n.news_category_id
```

This seems to work. But it do not show a category record which no news in the category. The query result only show category records only there is news with releated category.

How to show all category records with a sigle sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `left outer join` instead of an `inner join`.

See [this great explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I tried for a while. In fact it should use right outer join in this case, and should group by c.id.

Comment: @qichunren It is better to get used to left joins only and rearange tables accordingly, because when you start mixing left and right join in a complex query everybody - including you - will spend a lot of time trying to read it.